# Ruby instance variable changes unexpectedly

Tags: ruby

In the code below, a cluster has many points.

```
class Cluster
  attr_accessor :centroid, :points
  def initialize(centroid, *points)
    @centroid = centroid
    @points = points
  end
end

class Point
  attr_accessor :x, :y
  def initialize(x = 0, y = 0)
    @x = x
    @y = y
  end
end
```

An example of a `Cluster` object (lets us call this `c`):

```
#<Cluster:0x007ff5c123c210
 @centroid=#<Point:0x007ff5c123c288 @x=25, @y=125>,
 @points=
  [#<Point:0x007ff5c123c238 @x=25, @y=125>,
   #<Point:0x007ff5c1020120 @x=28, @y=145>]>
```

I am trying to calculate the mean of the points, and update `@centroid` without changing `@points`.

Let's say I have:

```
class Point
  def +(point)
    @x = @x + point.x
    @y = @y + point.y
    self
  end
  def /(num)
    @x = @x/num
    @y = @y/num
    self
  end
end
```

and to calculate the mean of all the points, I run:

```
c.centroid = c.points.reduce(&:+)/c.points.length
```

Then, `c` changes to:

```
#<Cluster:0x007ff5c123c210
 @centroid=#<Point:0x007ff5c1515ec8 @x=26, @y=135>,
 @points=
  [#<Point:0x007ff5c1515ec8 @x=26, @y=135>,
   #<Point:0x007ff5c1020120 @x=28, @y=145>]>
```

Note that first element of the `@points` is changed. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `+` method in `Point` modifies the point's members `@x` and `@y`. You need to return a new point with the calculated values instead:

```
def +(point)
  Point.new(@x + point.x, @y + point.y)
end

def /(num)
  Point.new(@x/num, @y/num)
end
```

Comment: BTW, it's not just `+`, the problem exists in `/`

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not pass an initial value to `reduce`, the first point became modified. You can pass a new point as the initial value to `reduce`, which will be modified and returned.

```
c.centroid = c.points.reduce(Point.new, &:+)/c.points.length
```

Comment: This would probably circumvent the problem, but IMO "operator like" methods should always return a new object instead of modifying the receiver. The latter can easily be achieved by `point += ...`.

Comment: @Stefan I agree. As the way for software architecture, you are right. I just showed a minimal modification to OP's code. If I were to do this myself, I would not have the OP's architecture in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @sawa. What architecture would you personally use in this context?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is caused by the + method modifying the point @x and @y values.

Try changing the + method to:

```
def +(point)
  x = @x + point.x
  y = @y + point.y

  self.class.new(x, y)
end
```